# Function paramater not changing when referenced outside of function

Tags: python, function, linked-list

```
class ListNode:
  # initialize a node
  def __init__(self, val,next = None):
    self.val = val
    self.next = next
  
  # allows you to print the list
  def __str__(self):
    temp = self
    arr = []
    while temp!= None:
      arr.append(temp.val)
      temp = temp.next
    return "->".join([str(i) for i in arr])

def change_test(link):
    link = ListNode(5)
    print(link) # this prints 5

test = ListNode(1)
print(test) # this is expected to print 1
change_test(test)
print(test) # this is expected to print 5 but its still printing 1
```

I don't know why the state of the function parameter isn't saving. For the specific usecase I'm going for, returning the object isn't an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you created a **new object**, which is what you're printing, and not the `ListNode` object you passed as a parameter.

I'm guessing this is what you want to do:

```
def change_test(link):
    link.val = 5
    print(link) # this prints 5

test = ListNode(1)
print(test) # this prints 1
change_test(test)
print(test) # this prints 5 as expected
```